# Getting "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator." error on checkout page

Tags: commerce

Drupal version:  9.5.2

On the checkout page when user tries to add new shipping address by selecting "+ Enter a new address" from selectlist, form for new address loads but shows error message "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."

This is the screeshot:[image]

In the error log following information is getting logged:

Location:   https://mysite.com/checkout/20145382/order_information?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&ajax_form=1

Referrer:   https://mysite.com/checkout/20145382/order_information

Message:    Illegal choice 181 in Payment method element.

Severity:   Error

What is the cause of this error and how can I solve it??

Comment: Is this a custom form? Have you customized it at all?

Comment: @Jaypan Not a custom form and haven't customized it.

Comment: You're not showing the critical part ... the payment options space. The error is likely just appearing when new address is selected b/c the form is validated and rebuilt via Ajax. Could it be the site doesn't show any valid payment option for the customer?